# Spring Bean Unable to Locate Configuration Properties Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testng

I am writing a test using TestNG and Spring Framework (along with Spring Boot), and am running into the application context being unable to locate a particular configuration properties bean.

The setup involves two separate configurations, both referenced by the test. A simple representation of the setup causing the issue would involve these configurations:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class SomePropertyConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "someConfiguration")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test.prefix")
    public CustomPropertyClass customPropertyClass(){
        return new CustomPropertyClass();
    }

}

@Configuration
public class SomeConfiguration {

    public ISomethingApi somethingApi(CustomPropertyClass customPropertyClass){
        return new SomethingApi(customPropertyClass.getProperty());
    }
}
```

The test is setup in a simple way, just to test a couple base properties:

```
@TestPropertySource("classpath:/test.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SomePropertyConfiguration.class, SomeConfiguration.class })
public class SomethingApiTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Inject
    private ISomethingApi somethingApi;

    @Test
    public void test(){
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

The end result of these setups is an exception where the configuration for `SomethingApi` cannot find a valid bean of type `CustomPropertyClass`.

It is worth noting that if `SomeConfiguration` is removed from the test, and `CustomPropertyClass` is injected into the test directly, everything works and the properties are the expected values, which is what is most perplexing about the issue - so something seems to be causing spring to not deal with order of wiring for beans correctly. I have similar setups in other projects which operate as expected, but I have been unable to find any meaningful differences that might cause this behavior (both projects are on the same major version of Spring and Spring Boot)

EDIT:

I have tried with and without `@Configuration` on `SomePropertyConfiguration`, without any change in results. In the other project referenced with this working, the property configuration class does not include that explicit annotation, so I left it off in the main example above. I also tried using an `@Autowired` field of the property bean in the second configuration and referencing it that way for the dependency, instead of as a parameter (in case that impacted order of wiring or something), which also had no impact on the results.

I am using Spring framework `5.1.7.RELEASE`, and Spring Boot `2.0.9.RELEASE`

Comment: You should generally be saying `@EnableConfigurationProperties(CustomPropertyClass.class)`.

Comment: I was under the impression that was an option instead of declaring in a function with `@Bean` to get it wired - in this case I am using `@ConfigurationProperties` with the `@Bean` on a function because the same property class will be re-used with different prefixes for different instances of configuration (not present in this example, as that is not yet setup in the problem project, and I was attempting to reduce the exmaple to the main elements for simplicity in describing the problem)

Comment: Ah, I see (you didn't include your actual CPC); that is an option (not the most common, but it does apply to your case). I note that your `SomePropertyConfiguration` snippet here does not have `@Configuration` on it; can you confirm that it does in your application?

Comment: It currently does not include `@Configuration`, but I did try that setup (apologies, I meant to include a list of a couple variations I have tried thus far but forgot to, I shall edit the question)

Answer (score 1):

After some additional investigation, I found the following in the logs

```
a definition for bean 'someConfiguration' already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override
```

it turns out that in this circumstance, the naming conventions in my project had caused a collision between the name of the property-class bean, and the project's overall configuration bean. Both beans and configuration classes appear to share a namespace, and will not cause a crash/error (directly) if they collide